# Can I add HTML5 elements to existing HTML documents?

Tags: html

So I have an existing HTML page that has a field for Last 4 digits of Credit Card:

```
<input value="" name="Last4ofCC" maxlength="4" id="Last4ofCC1">
```

Works great, but a feature request just came in to make it a numeric field and not allow non-numeric characters.

At first I thought of plugging in some Javascript, but then I thought, why not just use an HTML5 element.  I changed to the following:

```
<input type="number" value="" name="Last4ofCC" max="4" id="Last4ofCC1">
```

But not only does it still allow non-numeric characters, the max attribute doesn't work either!  I'm testing this on FireFox 8, so not sure what the problem is.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to include the proper doctype at the top of your page in addition to changing your input types.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

However, it's not going to do what you think it's going to. Setting an input as a `type="number"` will pretty much only get you the spinners on the side and tell the form what it *should* be. If you want to ensure only digits are entered, you will need to do a regex, like `/^\d+$/` on keyup.

More info on [HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/)

Comment: @Adam - key*up* is definitely better than key*down* but still misses pasting bad data in a field. Use that to catch as-you-type, but also use the _change_ event.

Comment: I guess there is no way around doing the Javascript check, thanks for clarifying that for me, good info.

Comment: @Mark - you're re-validating on the server too, I hope. No JS checks are perfect and can be tampered with and bypassed anyway.

Comment: I wasn't since it's an internal application so mistakes are rare, but good point, I'll add that in.

Comment: @StephenP you should have separate validation for your `change()` event than on your `keyup()`, but i agree that you should validate on both events. also, yes you should be validating on the server, but if it is truly an internal app then you could probably let it slide, especially since you most likely won't be hacking yourself ;)

Comment: @Jason I largely agree with you, especially on all the various validations, but crime statistics (in the U.S.) show that most attacks/theft from companies come from insiders - in spite of all we hear about organized criminal hackers.

Comment: @StephenP oh i agree for sure, my impression was that he was building an app for himself! haha... yeah if you are building an app where you are not the sole user, server side validation is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add HTML5 features to existing pages. Browser support to them is, at least at present, independent of any `doctype` stuff you may or may not have at the start of your page.

It is, however, probably not a good idea to use `type="number"` for reading four digits. It is meant for reading numeric data, and it will happily accept 42 without requiring any more digits, for example. Moreover, the user interface may even confuse the user. But if you use `type="number"`, you should in this case set `min="0"` and `max="9999"`.

A better HTML5 construct is `pattern="[0-9]{4}" required`. It is supposed to run a check on the input, checking that it consists of exactly four digits. This is supposed to happen even when JavaScript is disabled.

Since browser support is still rather limited, it’s a good idea to use JavaScript checks, too, as a convenience to the user.

Answer (score 1):

'max' indicates the maximum value allowed, not the maximum number of characters.

Comment: while true, this is not technically an answer to the question.

Comment: @Jason - Partial credit. He wanted to know what he was doing wrong. I believe he thought 'max' would limit this to four characters.

Answer (score 1):

Jason's answer is mostly correct. However, you should not do validation on keyup unless the user needs additional help. I'm the author of h5Validate. In the process of improving conversion rates in a large production shopping cart, we discovered that users get confused if they see a validation error message while they're still trying to type the number.

h5Validate first runs validation on change, and if the value is invalid, it will add keyup to help the user correct the field with each keystroke. This seems like a minor nitpick, but the difference it makes measures in the millions of dollars per year in revenue for large scale shopping cart systems.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, as far as I know Firefox doesn't support those yet, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29. Try Chrome to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the latest form support for Firefox here (it's supposed to be support):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML

Also check out:

http://caniuse.com/#search=form%20validation

This jQuery plugin will add support for all browsers though. It's a safe approach that still uses HTML5 syntax:

http://ericleads.com/h5validate/

Good luck!